# Unable to take input via google keyboard in android google chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, html

I am using chrome for testing my mobile webpage.
My Input box does not display any text when i type in it.
It displays when i use any other keyboard except google keyboards!
when i change settings to swift keyboard it displays the text input.
it also displays when i put the spell check off.

```
<div class="RG_input">
                                    <input type="text" class="CompanyName" id="txtName">
                                    <span id="spnErrorAppName" class="error" style="display: none;">Please enter name</span>
                                    <label for="input" class="register">
                                    </label>
                                    <i class="bar"></i>
                                </div>
```

Comment: a screenshot would be more helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have written a jquery, keycode validation for customer to entry only alphabet with space

> $(".CompanyName").keydown(function (e) { 46 == e.keyCode || 8 == e.keyCode || 9 == e.keyCode || 27 == e.keyCode || 13 == e.keyCode || 65 == e.keyCode && e.ctrlKey === !0 || e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39 || 32 == e.keyCode || 222 != e.keyCode && (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90) && e.preventDefault() });

which doesnt work in mobile browser
so please can anyone find the solution of it